# How do I open a CSV file that I uploaded with Carrierwave and Fog to Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have a model called **client_billing_file** where I use Carrierwave to upload a CSV file like this:

```
mount_uploader :billing_file_name, UsageFileUploader
```

and I schedule a job to run 5 minutes after commiting the creation of a new record:

```
after_commit :generate_usage_file, on: :create

def generate_usage_file
  Resque.enqueue_in(5.minutes, GenerateUsageFileQueue, id, admin.email)
end
```

This is my background job:

```
def self.perform(client_billing_file_id, email)
  cbf = ClientBillingFile.find(client_billing_file_id)
  filepath = cbf.billing_file_name.current_path
  csv_file = CSV.read(filepath, headers: true)
  .
  .
  .
end
```

This is working in my development and testing environments, but it fails when I try to open the CSV file in the staging environment (where it actually uploads the file to the S3 bucket). I checked the bucket and the file is getting uploaded to the specified directory correctly, but for some reason the job is throwing the following error:

```
Exception Errno::ENOENT
Error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - my_path/my_file.csv
```

Versions:

- Ruby 2.6.6
- Rails 4.2.11
- Carrierwave 0.8.0
- Fog 1.38.0

Comment: You might want to compare current directories.

Comment: the issue is likely that carrierwave is saving it to a local path in development. You need to read the bytes via the mount, something like  `csv = CSV.parse( cbf.billing_file_name.read)`

Comment: In your bg job, you probably need to explicitly tell CarrierWave to download the file. Not sure exactly what method I've used for this in the past, maybe `::CarrierWave::Uploader::Download.download!`. Check out `spec/uploader/download_spec.rb` for some examples.

Comment: @JaredBeck that was it! I just added a condition to download the file if I'm in staging or production and now CSV.read is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Jared Beck's idea and it's working now, basically I added this condition to my BG job:

```
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
  url = cbf.billing_file_name.url
  cbf.billing_file_name.download!(url)
end
```

So the final code looks like this:

```
def self.perform(client_billing_file_id, email)
  cbf = ClientBillingFile.find(client_billing_file_id)
  if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
    url = cbf.billing_file_name.url
    cbf.billing_file_name.download!(url)
  end
  filepath = cbf.billing_file_name.current_path
  csv_file = CSV.read(filepath, headers: true)
  .
  .
  .
end
```